# Convert str to float with pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to change all my column data from str to float but the problema is I have numbers and `'--'` too. 
I want to change all `'--'` to a `0.00` and then my objetivo variable could be work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('status.csv')    
objetivo = df['BP Booked Imps Budget (lifetime)'].astype(float)
```

error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: --`

csv:

```
BP Booked Imps Budget (lifetime), Imp
--,5555444
--,342345
--,245632
--,2345467
21345,3456
1234,34567
456,324567
123456,7654
--,6543
```

Comment: Please provide [MCVE], the expected output in particular.

Comment: I think you need `pd.to_numeric` as you also have strings in your column.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of what you're already doing, you could do

```
df['BP Booked Imps Budget (lifetime)'].replace('--', 0).astype(float)
```

A different approach would be

```
pd.to_numeric(df['BP Booked Imps Budget (lifetime)'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks bro! It Works!

Comment: Great, you're welcome. If you found the answer helpful, you can [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).